# "Invalid config field backend model: adminhtml/system_config_backend_secure" Error

Tags: php, magento

I have apparently done a sloppy upgrade to Magento 1.4.2.

At first, I was getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /home/rrmusicc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 385.
```

I found a solution for this in a forum so I applied that fix, now I'm getting this error:

```
Invalid config field backend model: adminhtml/system_config_backend_secure
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you created model adminhtml/system_config_backend_secure ?

Comment: I haven't. I'm not sure how to either.